# MyriadPro и верстка

Tags: html, css

Всем привет!

Прислали макет на верстку и там основной шрифт - myriadpro. Как лучше всего добиться уверенности в том, что он будет нормально везде работать. Он же вроде как поставляется с фотошопом и не является стандартным в разных ОСках?

Как вариант, я думаю подключить его с помощью @font-face.. Нормально или есть еще варианты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добиться уверенности по поводу кроссбраузерности - прогнать через [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator). Белка отдаст несколько файлов для различных браузеров + CSS. Поставляется с Фотошопом, [не бесплатен](http://paratype.ru/pstore/default.asp?fcode=1544&letter=M&SRC=LT). Подключается через @font-face (других вариантов я не знаю).

Comment: Ну я так и думаю, что других вариантов нет. Кстати вам порекомендую вместо Font Squirrel (если используете) этот сервис: http://www.font2web.com/
Белочка кириллицу вроде с шрифтов удаляет и они, иногда рваными краями получаются. А тут все норм :)

Comment: Спасибо, буду иметь в виду. Зато в белочке можно оставлять только те символы, которые нужны.

Comment: Внешний вид важнее, ИМХО) Вам также спасибо!